# is there any NETBEANs plugin that can give design view of webpages?

Tags: netbeans, web-applications

i am developing a web application and working with java servlets and JSP i need to view the design of JSP pages in NETBEANS is there any plugin etc. to do so

Comment: no one ans or comments on it no one knows or not interested to ans ............................................

Answer (score 0):

There's this one:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=3941